# can i use two repository in the same service?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-data

my service.Impl class :

```
 @Service
 public class HevenServiceImpl implements IHevenService     {
 /*
  * 
  * Injecting DAO
  */
 @Resource
 private HevenRepositoryDAO  repository;
 @Resource
 private DecompteRepositoryDAO repository2;
```

what is the impact ? can we get **dirty-read** problem !!?

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes you can! But you should follow the single responsibility principle. What it means is, don't let your service layer know about repositories, rather have some manager layer in between(say ServiceManager). ServiceManager will call different set of classes(say RepoManager). Each RepoManager deals with one repository and exposes functions to do all low level sort of things(CRUD operations with transactions management, retry, caching etc can be handled here). Your ServiceManager should deals with multiple RepoManagers and will have the business logic. The Service impl. should just delegate the call to appropriate managers and can do some other stuff like exception handling at single place etc. This means lot of extra classes, which doesn't worth in fairly simple component but adds lot of value as your application/component grows. Use your own judgement to atleast segregate the service layer from repositories.

Comment: Of course it works. For me I followed the logic of my architecture : 
- HevenEntity->HevenRepo->HevenService->HevenServiceImpl
- DecompteEntity->DecompteRepo->DecompteService->DecompteServiceImpl.
In my process i need to create a decompte at the same time when i create a heven, so in **HevenServiceImpl** i inject **DecompteService** .

I asked the Qte because i read an article about how using two repository in the same transaction can cause a dirty-read problem !! 
I seek an explanation if it's true !